# Calculate first principal component direction and scores

Tags: pca, covariance, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

Given that x1 =  (9, 9, −18)^T and x2 = (18, 9, 9)^T with eigendecomposition of its sample covariance matrix Σ = cov(X)

[image]

How do I calculate the first two principal component direction and the principal component scores of x1 and x2 corresponding to the first two principal component direction

Answer (score 1):

The columns in the first matrix of the expansion corresponds to *principal components* of yours, corresponding to *eigenvalues* in the diagonal, in the same order. Note that they're unit norm, i.e. direction vectors. So, the first two largest eigenvectors, i.e. *principal components*, are the third and first ones; and the scores of $x_i$ are the dot products of $x_i$ with these components.

Comment: I'm having trouble following this, because you seem to be asserting that the $x_i$ are eigenvectors of $\Sigma$--but they are not.

Comment: If i understand this correctly, first principal component direction is 4 and second principal component direction is 2, the scores are (4 2)^T ⋅ (9, 9, −18) ⋅  (4 2) and (4 2)^T ⋅ (18, 9, 9) ⋅  (4 2) respectively?

Comment: Principal components are vectors with same dimension as your data vectors. First PC is [1/3,2/3, -2/3] for example, which is the third column of the first matrix. @whuber, I corrected a terrible verbal mistake of mine, but I don't seem to understand if it addresses your comment.

Comment: It does, thank you: I had hoped to see the term "dot product" appear somewhere in the answer!

Comment: Ok so first PC direction is dot product of the following, (9, 9, −18) ^T ⋅ (1/3 2/3 -2/3) ⋅  (9, 9, −18)  @whuber. Sorry, I am really struggling to understand the application.

Comment: Direction is a vector, score is a scalar. I've already told the first PC direction in my last comment. For the score of $x_i$ on the 1-st PC: you have $x_i ⋅ pc_1$, where ⋅ denotes the dot product.